# Extract Data from Dataframe (or matrix) in R by pattern(s)

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a matrix (that I converted to dataframe) that I am trying to count # of rows with certain pattern(s). Example of data frame is below:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7
S1  A   3528    1632    10.40249433 3   3
S2  A   13629   3256    5.018710103 3   3
S3  A   7769    2732    8.829965246 30  30
S4  B   8340    2679    3.597122302 3   3
S5  B   10027   2752    4.138825172 3   3
S6  B   10493   3071    3.840655675 3   3
S7  C   1295    784 13.43629344 3   3
S8  C   6482    2248    5.630978093 30  30
S9  C   11452   3481    4.042961928 3   3
```

1) Original data was matrix and I converted to dataframe (by having file then importing as data frame, not sure if that's the best way) but it works

2) My goal is to count the # of rows with specific pattern. For instance, how many rows have Col2==C and Col3>3000.

3) I tried

`nrow(dataframe[which(dataframe$Col2=="C"),])`

The above is working but when trying to combine with the other condition of Col3 it is  returning Null and I tried different ways and it is not working. I am also not sure if changing matrix to data frame like what I did above (exporting matrix, then importing as data frame) is the most efficienct way. Appreciate assistance.

Comment: `x[ x$Col2 == "C" & x$Col3 > 3000,]`? I recommend against `which` in this case (though there might be times I would use it).

Comment: thanks! Why would you recommend against which ? Also, is the method above to convert matrix to data frame the best one? I couldn't find a direct function in R for that

Comment: Consider using the `tidyverse` package; the `filter()` function can make this a bit clearer, e.g. `filter(x, Col2 == "C", Col3 > 3000)`

Comment: `which` can return `integer(0)`, which (no pun intended) can be counter-productive at times. In this case, it will do what you need: return a vector of indices that match what you need; but then again, so does a vector of all `FALSE`, which is what you get with what is inside the call to `which`. So in this case, all `FALSE` and `integer(0)` have the same exact effect, so adding `which` provides nothing (except an extra nano-second or two wasted).